# How would I solve this Encoder?

Tags: java, arrays, string, encoder

Before I start, it's worth noting that I am a beginner learning to write Java code. In order to learn, I am going through coding bats and solving them. I just came to a problem where I have no clue where to start, as the way of solving the problem I had in mind does not work. [Here is a link the coding bat.](http://codingbat.com/prob/p227093) The description is:

> When given a Array of Strings (ALL UPPERCASE) words change every letter to a letter that is 10 places away.

I think the way to solve this problem is to go through the array of strings, change each individual string into an array of chars, and "encode" it, then after that return the brand new string into the array. I only got so far until I noticed when I tried to convert the string to an array, I got an error. Here is picture of the code I have written so far: https://gyazo.com/c2de83026b14d91cc908d853bf5834fe

So I guess my real question is... How would I go about solving this problem? My idea does not seem to work and most of the string commands that I tried using within the array of strings are not working.

Comment: You can create an array and put the alphabets in the array. As you loop through the string using `yourString.charAt(i)` find the index the character is in and add ten to that index to find the letter you need to change the current letter to. Don't forget to use `mod` so that your final range after adding ten stay below 26.

Comment: no-one wants a picture of your code. Code is text, so please paste it into the question. Then it's searchable, and copyable if someone wants to adapt it for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct but you use to toCharArray() method over **string array**. This method is used *string* to *char array*. Your code can be like this:

```
public String[]  encoder(String [] words){
    ...
    //loop over string
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        encodeString(words[i]);
    }

    ....
}

private String encodeString(String word){

    //toCharArray usage
    //loop over char
    for (char c : word.toCharArray()) {
        encodeChar(c);
    }

    ....
}

private String encodeChar(char c){
    //Your char conversion algorithm 
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method :

```
  private void buildReq(String input, int interval) {
    try {
        interval = interval % 26;
        int maxCap = Character.valueOf('Z');
        int minCap = Character.valueOf('A') - 1;
        input = input.toUpperCase();
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            int charVal = input.charAt(i);
            if (charVal >= minCap && charVal <= maxCap) {
                int outVal = charVal + interval;
                if (outVal > maxCap)
                    outVal = outVal % maxCap + minCap;
                output.append((char) outVal);
            } else {
                output.append((char) charVal);
            }
        }
        txtResponse.setText(output);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```